# Store the fields to mongodb which are not passed in the request body as null or empty(collection is defined using mongoose schema)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Below is my schema:

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    category: String,
    },{
    versionKey: false 
});
```

When I post data by removing any of the field as shown below(category is removed):

```
{
  "title":"Book1",
  "author":"abc"
}
```

My actual POST response is:

```
{
  "_id": "5d47cbe70d7cae1e847a00f0",
  "title": "Book1",
  "author": "abc"
}
```

I want the response should be like :

```
  {
      "_id": "5d47cbe70d7cae1e847a00f0",
      "title": "Book1",
      "author": "abc",
      "category":""
    }
```

How to achieve this in nodejs using mongoose schema?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html) to set default values.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of @Ravi, changing your schema with default values will return as desired

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
title: {type: String, default: ""}
author: {type: String, default: ""}
category: {type: String, default: ""},
},{
versionKey: false 
});
```